# Multiplying 4*4 matrices

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, matrix

I'm multiplying 4x4 matrices for learning purposes. How can I optimize this for performance?

**HTML**

```
<table class="matrex-1">
    <tr><td class="0-0">-1</td><td class="1-0">0</td><td class="2-0">-1</td><td class="3-0">0</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="0-1">8</td><td class="1-1">-9</td><td class="2-1">8</td><td class="3-1">-9</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="0-2">5</td><td class="1-2">6</td><td class="2-2">2</td><td class="3-2">-4</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="0-3">-2</td><td class="1-3">7</td><td class="2-3">-8</td><td class="3-3">1</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="matrex-2">
    <tr><td class="0-0">4</td><td class="1-0">3</td><td class="2-0">4</td><td class="3-0">3</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="0-1">-1</td><td class="1-1">7</td><td class="2-1">-1</td><td class="3-1">7</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="0-2">5</td><td class="1-2">2</td><td class="2-2">9</td><td class="3-2">-3</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="0-3">6</td><td class="1-3">2</td><td class="2-3">4</td><td class="3-3">1</td></tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table class="matrex-3">
    <tr><td class="0-0"></td><td class="1-0"></td><td class="2-0"></td><td class="3-0"></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="0-1"></td><td class="1-1"></td><td class="2-1"></td><td class="3-1"></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="0-2"></td><td class="1-2"></td><td class="2-2"></td><td class="3-2"></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="0-3"></td><td class="1-3"></td><td class="2-3"></td><td class="3-3"></td></tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
var first, fifth,
    second, sixth,
    third, seventh,
    forth, eighth;

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {                                                   
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            first = parseInt($('.matrex-1 td.0-' + i).text());
            second = parseInt($('.matrex-2 td.' + j + '-0').text());
            third = parseInt($('.matrex-1 td.1-' + i).text());
            forth = parseInt($('.matrex-2 td.' + j + '-1').text());
            fifth = parseInt($('.matrex-1 td.2-' + i).text());
            sixth = parseInt($('.matrex-2 td.' + j + '-2').text());
            seventh = parseInt($('.matrex-1 td.3-' + i).text());
            eighth = parseInt($('.matrex-2 td.' + j + '-3').text());

            $('.matrex-3 td.' + j + '-' + i).text(first * second + third * forth + fifth * sixth + seventh * eighth);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the other guy did the math, I'll do the web part.

It would be better to collect all your values first *then* do the operation. Accessing the DOM is expensive. Doing it `n^2` times would be very slow. Using jQuery inside `n^2` is even terrible as jQuery parses your selector, traverses the DOM, wraps it in a jQuery object, and all the browser-compatibility stuff without you noticing it. You can use any of the available native methods to retrieve the values.

Depending on your math, you can represent your matrix as a 1D array (a 4x4 would be an array of 16 in length), or a 2D nested array(a 4x4 would be an array of 4 arrays, each with 4 items). A 1D array will save you memory at the cost of computation, while a 2D array is simpler to visualize, but you'll use up at least `n+1` arrays.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...,16].

// or

[
  [1,2,3,4],
  [5,6,7,8],
  ...
  [.,.,.,16]
]
```

For `parseInt`, you'll need to provide the radix as a second parameter. Otherwise, if you omit it, it will assume that your strings are in octal and not decimal. Your math might be off. Additionally, if `parseInt` encounters a non-numeric character *first*, it returns `NaN`. Then all your math will result in `NaN`. Always check for the results of `parseInt`.

Answer (score 3):

For small matrix multiplications, I think it is typically fastest (surprisingly) to implement the basic matrix multiplication you learn in elementary/middle school, which gives us an asymptotic runtime complexity of n^3, where n is the length and width of the arrays (assuming both arrays have the same dimensions and aspect ratios).

In Pseudo code, this algorithm goes as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            resultingArray[i][j] = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                resultingArray[i][j] += firstArray[i][k] * secondArray[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return resultArray;
```

For larger matrices, typically 30 and up (subjective), there is an algorithm called Strassen's Algorithm that multiplies matrices with an approximate asymptotic runtime complexity of 2^n, again, where n is the length and width of the matrices. This problem is a recursive algorithm that breaks the problem into a lot of sub-problems by breaking down and working on web-matrices. This algorithm typically has a numeric "cross-over" point variable that is defined by the developer and represents the size bound of the matrices where it would be *more* efficient to simply multiply using the standard matrix multiplication algorithm. The algorithm would roughly go as follows:

```
if (n <= crossOverPoint) {
        resultArray = basicMatrixMult (n, firstArray, secondArray, resultArray);
    } else {
        double[][] firstArraySubArray1 = partitionSubArray (firstArray, 0, (n / 2), 0, (n / 2));
        double[][] firstArraySubArray2 = partitionSubArray (firstArray, (n / 2), n, (n / 2), n);

        double[][] secondArraySubArray1 = partitionSubArray (secondArray, 0, (n / 2), 0, (n / 2));
        double[][] secondArraySubArray2 = partitionSubArray (secondArray, 0, (n / 2), (n / 2), n);

        resultArray = strassenMatrixMult ((n / 2), addMatrices (firstArraySubArray1, firstArraySubArray2),
                                                 addMatrices (firstArraySubArray1, firstArraySubArray1), 
                                                 resultArray);
    }
    return resultArray;
```

Here's some more info in case you wanted to read up on Strassen's Algorithm:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm